# Is it mandatory to use Drools KIE execution server to fire a rule?

Tags: rest, drools, workbench

All,
Is it mandatory to use Drools KIE execution server to fire a rule ?
What about passing the required data to a Rules jar as a standalone approach instead of REST ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need at all to use the Kie Execution Server, no. 
Following [Drools' User Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.0.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#_user_guide) you can learn how to create a Kie Container in Java and how to get a Kie Session from it.

For example, if you have your rules in your classpath, you can try something like this:

```
KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieContainer kContainer = kieServices.getKieClasspathContainer();

KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession();
Applicant applicant = new Applicant( "Mr John Smith", 16 );    
ksession.insert( applicant );
ksession.fireAllRules();
```

Once you have your session, you can start feeding it some facts and exercising its rules.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! I got confused  since I am seeing most of the examples using KIE server , they are triggering the RULES using REST call. Is there any limitation in the standalone approach ?